# HTML Horizontal Scrolling within DIV without page scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a page with several divs.  The first div contains tables that I want to display horizontally side by side, and if they contain more than the width of the screen, I want a horizontal scroll just for that one div.  No matter how I modify the display setting the tables stack in the div 3 x 3 (due to the width of each table being 30%) with a horizontal scroll bar below that does nothing.

Code:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

body .contained {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: inline;
  width 100%;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: AliceBlue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: .5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  overflow: none;
}

.title {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 18px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: PowderBlue;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: black;
}

button:hover,
a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.float-container {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: White;
}
```

```html
<div class="contained">
  <div class="card">
    <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
    <p class="title">George Larson</p>
    <p>Telecom Specialist</p>
    <p>Information Systems</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="div2">
    <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
    <p class="title">George Larson</p>
    <p>Telecom Specialist</p>
    <p>Information Systems</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="div2">
    <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
    <p class="title">George Larson</p>
    <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="div2">
    <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
    <p class="title">George Larson</p>
    <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="div2">
    <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
    <p class="title">George Larson</p>
    <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="div2">
    <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
    <p class="title">George Larson</p>
    <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="div2">
    <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
    <p class="title">George Larson</p>
    <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="card" id="div3">
    <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
    <p class="title">George Larson</p>
    <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="div3">
    <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
    <p class="title">George Larson</p>
    <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="div3">
    <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
    <p class="title">George Larson</p>
    <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="div3">
    <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
    <p class="title">George Larson</p>
    <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="div3">
    <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
    <p class="title">George Larson</p>
    <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="div3">
    <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
    <p class="title">George Larson</p>
    <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this using Flexbox.

I changed `display: inline` to `display: flex`. Not really sure why `inline` was chosen, because it really makes your `div` behave like a `span`. Also, `overflow-x: auto` because you would want the scrollbar only when overflow happens.

```css
body .contained {
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also added `flex-shrink: 0` and removed `float: left` to the `.card`. More on this change on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23691645/2950032)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="enUS">

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    
    body .contained {
      overflow-x: auto; /* MODIFIED */
      display: flex; /* MODIFIED */
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .card {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      width: 200px;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 25px;
      background-color: AliceBlue;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: .5px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      /* float: left; /* REMOVED */
      flex-shrink: 0; /* ADDED */
      overflow: none;
    }
    
    .title {
      color: grey;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      background-color: PowderBlue;
      border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 22px;
      color: black;
    }
    
    button:hover,
    a:hover {
      opacity: 0.7;
    }
    
    .float-container {
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: White;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="contained">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
      <p class="title">George Larson</p>
      <p>Telecom Specialist</p>
      <p>Information Systems</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card" id="div2">
      <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
      <p class="title">George Larson</p>
      <p>Telecom Specialist</p>
      <p>Information Systems</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="div2">
      <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
      <p class="title">George Larson</p>
      <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="div2">
      <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
      <p class="title">George Larson</p>
      <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="div2">
      <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
      <p class="title">George Larson</p>
      <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="div2">
      <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
      <p class="title">George Larson</p>
      <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="div2">
      <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
      <p class="title">George Larson</p>
      <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="card" id="div3">
      <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
      <p class="title">George Larson</p>
      <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="div3">
      <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
      <p class="title">George Larson</p>
      <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="div3">
      <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
      <p class="title">George Larson</p>
      <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="div3">
      <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
      <p class="title">George Larson</p>
      <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="div3">
      <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
      <p class="title">George Larson</p>
      <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="div3">
      <h1>Discovery Directory</h1>
      <p class="title">George Larson</p>
      <p>Telecom Specialist<br>Information Systems</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been trying for days on this.  It worked exactly like I wanted.  As for the display inline, I was playing with so many options.  You rock.

Comment: Happy to help! Would recommend learning about the box model and also flexbox (maybe CSS grid later). I love this resource https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by specifying the overflow for the div you want to scroll.

Like:

```
<div id="scrollable">
Scrollable Content
</div>

<style>
div#scrollable{
overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
```

Check it out for more detailed description of usage :
[Examples with information](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)
[Exact example of usage](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow)

Scrollbars with

```
...
 body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
...
```

Changed to

```
...
 body {
      overflow:hidden
    }
...
```

Results:

[image: Overflow:Hidden]

Without the changeset:

[image: Original code]

Comment: Just tried that and it took away the scrollbar and still stacked.

Comment: Ok, I see... You need to change the  body { overflow-x: hidden;  overflow-y:auto} to just {overflow:hidden} it will hide all the scrollbars except the ones you put the above code on

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this, maazadeeb got me the answer I was looking for. Have a great day.